# C# rest api mail gun gives forbiden access status

Tags: c#, rest, mailgun

Good day, I am trying now to do email vertification, and followed all instructions but i get response status Unauthorized

```
private bool SendEmail(string body, string email)
    {
        //create client
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3");

        client.Authenticator =
            new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
            "02a4bca7b2e0c72e98841b20beef1585-69210cfc-a7bc0929");

        var request = new RestRequest();

        request.AddParameter("domain", "sandbox4706f89b4150439ebca3c380f3fa96d0.mailgun.org");
        request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
        request.AddParameter("from", "Ecommerce sandbox Mail<postmaster@sandbox4706f89b4150439ebca3c380f3fa96d0.mailgun.org>");
        request.AddParameter("to", email);
        request.AddParameter("subject", "Email Vertfication Email");
        request.AddParameter("text", body);
        request.Method = Method.Post;

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        return response.IsSuccessful;

    }
```

Do anyone had the same problem? I am conecting from EU so changed rest Client from  https://api.mailgun.net/v3 to https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3
If I use  https://api.mailgun.net/v3 I get response status Unauthorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Mailgun changed something in API but forgot to change the documentation. If you go to your domain dashboard and select API, you can see that base URL is different from the one in example

[image: api base URL]

So, base URL shouldn't be `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/` but [https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox....mailgun.org`](https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox....mailgun.org%60)

Also, make sure that email you're sending to is added to Authorized Recipients for your domain (see how to add it in [knowledge base](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients))

[image]

Once you have correct base URL and authorized (and verified recipient), you can send your email. So, in your example, it would be like this (look at comments also):

```
//note the URL with domain
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox4706f89b4150439ebca3c380f3fa96d0.mailgun.org");

client.Authenticator =
    new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
    "02a4bca7b2e0c72e98841b20beef1585-69210cfc-a7bc0929");

var request = new RestRequest();

//request.AddParameter("domain", ... is not needed anymore becasue of base URL
//also, Resource is now without {domain} parameter
request.Resource = "/messages";
request.AddParameter("from", "Ecommerce sandbox Mail<postmaster@sandbox4706f89b4150439ebca3c380f3fa96d0.mailgun.org>");
//this mail should be authorized recipient
request.AddParameter("to", email);
request.AddParameter("subject", "Email Vertfication Email");
request.AddParameter("text", body);
request.Method = Method.Post;

var response = client.Execute(request);

return response.IsSuccessful;
```

... And that should send the email without Unauthorized error